# Why I can't get element by ref using this.$refs in Vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem with accessing a component's element that has a ref attribute.

Here is the sample code. I have a DateTimePicker.vue component, wherein I set a unique ref for the element.

```
<datepicker :ref="datePickerInternal.ref"></datepicker>
<timepicker :ref="timePickerInternal.ref"></timepicker>
```

I can get the ref of both datepicker and timepicker so I think there's no problem in initializing their values.

But when I tried to access to my Parent Component (datetimepicker.vue) is I receiving a null values for both of them.

The ref for datepicker is **filter-express-item-filter-datetimepicker-range-from10-datepicker-ref** and for timepicker, the ref is **filter-express-item-filter-datetimepicker-range-from10-timepicker-ref**

---

So when I tried to access both of them by using:

```
mounted: function() {
    if (this.$refs['dateTimePicker'] !== undefined) {
        this.setDateTimePickerCustomWidth(this.$refs['dateTimePicker']);
    }
},

methods: {
    setDateTimePickerCustomWidth(dateTimePicker) {
        let datePickerRef = dateTimePicker.$data.datePickerPropsInternal.ref; 
        let timePickerRef = dateTimePicker.$data.timePickerPropsInternal.ref;

        console.log(datePickerRef, timePickerRef); 
        // when I tried to console.log() I can get the reference of both. So the problem is I can access the element by using ref???

        console.log("refs = ", this.$refs[datePickerRef]); 
        // I get "refs = ", null
    }
```

Comment: `dateTimePicker.$data.datePickerPropsInternal.ref` What are you trying to do here ?

Comment: Why is it `datePickerInternal` in one place and `datePickerPropsInternal` in the other? Should that last line be referencing `dateTimePicker.$refs` instead of `this.$refs`? The parent child relationships are not at all clear here.

Comment: I'm sorry this should be datePickerPropsInternal instead of datePickerInternal sir @skirtle

Comment: @MichalLevý I'm trying to get the ref that I set on another component.

Comment: @Star Then you should  do this: `let datePickerRef = dateTimePicker.$refs["datePickerPropsInternal.ref"];`. Also read the @tony19 answer. Are those your own vue components ?

Answer (score 2):

The `mounted` lifecycle hook [does not guarantee that all children are rendered](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted). Assuming the `ref` child is not conditionally rendered with `v-if`, you could move the referenced code into a `vm.$nextTick` callback, where the `ref` would be available:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      let datePickerRef = /* existent ref name */
      console.log(this.$refs[datePickerRef]) // => not undefined
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to bind ref.

```
<div id="app">
  My name is <input v-model="name" ref="myinput">
</div>

    const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    name:''
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.myinput," : ref")
    if(localStorage.name) this.name = localStorage.name;
  },
  watch:{
    name(newName) {
      localStorage.name = newName;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi. I have a problem because I need to name the ref as unique because this is a component that will reuse again. So I'm trying to name the ref as name + id.

Comment: Are those your own component ?

Comment: @Star Reuse doesn't explain the need for dynamic refs. The refs are scoped to a single component so name collisions cannot occur between instances.